# Video slow to load for no obvious reason

Tags: html, video, html5-video, autoplay

I am trying to figure out why my autoplay video takes so long to begin playing on mobile browsers. I have tried everything even going so far as to reduce it from 30mb to 3mb. I am aware of the mp4 'fast start' and 'web optimized' options that move the moov atom to the front of the file but I've encoded it with both Adobe and Handbrake and it still lags. My phone's internet speed is showing a test of 37mbps but a 3mb video is taking almost 10 secs (!) to start playing on both chrome and safari and no matter what I do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's because my hosting plan doesn't allow for video, I was unaware. I moved the videos to dropbox and changed the src and now they load faster.